# How to arrange images using HTML and CSS with containers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having issues arranging my images with containers. My images are a bit too spread out and I would like them to be a bit closer to one another. I decided to dynamically scale down my images and put them into containers thanks to a suggestion made in an earlier post but now I'm not sure how to set the images to the positioning I want.

I've tried messing with the width and directions but I still can't get the format I want. Here is my code. Any other suggestions such as formatting or development would be greatly appreciated as I'm still very new to learning HTML and CSS.

```css
.item-list {       /*parent container styles*/        
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;          /* allows flex properties */
    flex-direction: row;     /* keeps elements in a row */
    flex-wrap: wrap;        /* wraps elements when they reach the edge of the screen */
}

.img-container {        /*img container styles*/        
    max-width: 33.33%;
    width: 33.33%;
    display: grid;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
 }      
img {            /* img styles */
    width: 100%;        
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
    <div class="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/keychain.html" class="href">
            <img id="keychain1" src="Images/8.webp" alt="keychain1" title="keychain1">
            <section>
                <p>Chainsaw Man Acrylic Keychain</p>
                <hr>
                <p>$10.00</p>
            </section>
        </a>  
    </div>
    
    <div class="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/keychain2.html" class="href"> 
            <img id="keychain2" src="Images/7.webp" alt="keychain2" title="keychain2">
            <section>
                <p>Animal Acrylic Keychain</p>
                <hr>
                <p>$10.00</p>
            </section>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class ="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/stickers.html" class="href">
            <img id="stickers" src="Images/9.webp" alt="stickers" title="stickers">
            <section>
                <p>Stickers</p>
                <hr>
                <p>$2.00-$6.00</p>
            </section>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class ="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/photocard1.html" class="href">
            <img id="Photocard1" src="Images/10.webp" alt="photocard1" title="photocard1">
            <section>
                <p>Photocard Print (Ver 1 Designs)</p>
                <hr>
                <p>$3.75</p>
            </section>       
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class ="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/photocard2.html" class="href">
            <img id="Photocard2" src="Images/11.webp" alt="photocard2" title="photocard2">
            <section>
                <p>Photocard Print (Ver 3 Designs)</p>
                <hr>
                <p>$3.75-$12</p>
            </section> 
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should show your current output, and your expected output.

Comment: We don't need to see all of the HTML & CSS for the entire page. It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Comment: @TimR is this a little better?

Comment: @SallylovesLightning It should be able to show my output now

Comment: It is a little better because you created a snippet with the code. However, you did not create a **minimal and reproducible** example. I am *guessing* that you are seeking help with the broken images in the product cards. Thefore, that's all that should be included in the snippet. There are many websites that offer placeholder images.

Comment: @TimR Would this be better? I minimized my code to only show the direct problem, also as for the problem, the issue is that if you press full page, u can see that the images are far apart from one another. I would like them to be a bit closer to one another and was wondering how I can do that.

Comment: You are saying your images are far apart. I guess because your actual images are small in resolution? Because if I update it with high res images [this is what I can see](https://codepen.io/rakibul2010islam/pen/LYXaEyO). Can you please check and let us know what exactly you want it to look like?

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html This is what my images look like now, here is what I want them to look more like this: https://hanahaki02.bigcartel.com/products (I'm trying to replicate a friend's website to learn HTML and CSS)

Comment: @Mcteve The link you provided for your website is in your local server and it is not accessible for any of us. But I did see your friend's website and I can say that your images can be easily organizable like that. But you need to use high resolution images and then add margin to your image containers. I just provided an answer. You can look at that.

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam TYSM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some margins to your image containers and added the dummy images to show you how it looks. You can copy these codes and then use your own images to see the result.

```css
.item-list{       /*parent container styles*/            
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;          /* allows flex properties */
    flex-direction: row;     /* keeps elements in a row */
    flex-wrap: wrap;        /* wraps elements when they reach the edge of the screen */
    justify-content: center;
}

.img-container {        /*img container styles*/            
    max-width: 33.33%;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 1%;
    display: grid;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

img {           /* img styles */
    width: 100%               
}
```

```html
<div class="item-list">
    <div class="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/keychain.html" class="href">
            <img id="keychain1" src="https://picsum.photos/900/900?random=1" alt="keychain1" title="keychain1">
            <section>
                <p>Chainsaw Man Acrylic Keychain</p>
                <hr>
                <p>$10.00</p>

            </section>
        </a>  
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/keychain2.html" class="href"> 
            <img id="keychain2" src="https://picsum.photos/900/900?random=2" alt="keychain2" title="keychain2">
            <section>
                <p>Animal Acrylic Keychain</p>
                <hr>
                <p>$10.00</p>
            </section>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class ="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/stickers.html" class="href">
            <img id="stickers" src="https://picsum.photos/900/900?random=3" alt="stickers" title="stickers">
            <section>
                <p>Stickers</p>
                <hr>
                <p>$2.00-$6.00</p>                 
            </section>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class ="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/photocard1.html" class="href">
            <img id="Photocard1" src="https://picsum.photos/900/900?random=4" alt="photocard1" title="photocard1">
            <section>
                <p>Photocard Print (Ver 1 Designs)</p>
                <hr>
                <p>$3.75</p>
            </section>       
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class ="img-container">
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/photocard2.html" class="href">
            <img id="Photocard2" src="https://picsum.photos/900/900?random=5" alt="photocard2" title="photocard2">
            <section>
                <p>Photocard Print (Ver 3 Designs)</p>
                <hr>
                <p>$3.75-$12</p>
            </section> 
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have commenting permissions yet, but like the first comment says from Sally, it would be nice to have some more information on what you have vs. what you want.

If you're just looking to get the images closer together, you can adjust the width of `.img-container a`.

```
.img-container a {
    width: 80%;
  }
```